# Checkvalue for display form element interfering with each other

Tags: javascript

I have a select box where one particular value is selected another field shows up.

I have no knowledge of javascript and have taken this code from somewhere. 
I have this javascript in multiple places in the same form. But, my script works only on one input. If I select another from another select box, the value of previous input closes, the thing which I don't want. This will be well understood if you see the code.

The link where you can check the issue:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6hheckao/)

Javascript:

```js
function checkvalue(val) {
  if (val === "NewSale")
    document.getElementById('actualamt').style.display = 'block';
  else
    document.getElementById('actualamt').style.display = 'none';

  if (val === "SchoolWearAccessories")
    document.getElementById('schoolwear').style.display = 'block';
  else
    document.getElementById('schoolwear').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<form>
  Product Category:
  <select name="category" required onchange='checkvalue(this.value)'>
    <option value="">Select Product Category</option>
    <option value="School Uniforms">School Uniforms</option>
    <option value="SchoolWearAccessories">School Wear Accessories</option>
    <option value="Hospital Uniforms">Hospital Uniforms</option>
    <option value="Corporate Uniforms">Corporate Uniforms</option>
    <option value="Industrial Uniforms">Industrial Uniforms</option>
    </select>

  <div id="schoolwear" style="display:none;">
    Sub Category:
    <select name="subcategory">
    <option value="">Select Product Category</option>
    <option value="Uniform Sweaters">Uniform Sweaters</option>
    <option value="School Belts">School Belts</option>
    <option value="School Ties">School Ties</option>
    <option value="Uniform Socks and Shoes">Uniform Socks and Shoes</option>
    <option value="School Caps">School Caps</option>
    <option value="School Bags">School Bags</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  Tag:
  <select name="producttag" onchange='checkvalue(this.value)'>
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="New">New</option>
    <option value="Sale">Sale</option>
    <option value="NewSale">New and Sale</option>
    </select>

  <div id="actualamt" style="display:none;">
    Actual Amount:
    <input type="number" name="actualamt" step="any" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want both of them to be displayed on selection then simply use two different `onchange` functions like this

```js
function checkvalue(val) {
 if (val === "SchoolWearAccessories")
    document.getElementById('schoolwear').style.display = 'block';
  else
    document.getElementById('schoolwear').style.display = 'none';
}

function checkvalue1(val) {
  if (val === "NewSale")
    document.getElementById('actualamt').style.display = 'block';
  else
    document.getElementById('actualamt').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<form>
  Product Category:
  <select name="category" required onchange='checkvalue(this.value)'>
    <option value="">Select Product Category</option>
    <option value="School Uniforms">School Uniforms</option>
    <option value="SchoolWearAccessories">School Wear Accessories</option>
    <option value="Hospital Uniforms">Hospital Uniforms</option>
    <option value="Corporate Uniforms">Corporate Uniforms</option>
    <option value="Industrial Uniforms">Industrial Uniforms</option>
    </select>

  <div id="schoolwear" style="display:none;">
    Sub Category:
    <select name="subcategory">
    <option value="">Select Product Category</option>
    <option value="Uniform Sweaters">Uniform Sweaters</option>
    <option value="School Belts">School Belts</option>
    <option value="School Ties">School Ties</option>
    <option value="Uniform Socks and Shoes">Uniform Socks and Shoes</option>
    <option value="School Caps">School Caps</option>
    <option value="School Bags">School Bags</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  Tag:
  <select name="producttag" onchange='checkvalue1(this.value)'>
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="New">New</option>
    <option value="Sale">Sale</option>
    <option value="NewSale">New and Sale</option>
    </select>

  <div id="actualamt" style="display:none;">
    Actual Amount:
    <input type="number" name="actualamt" step="any" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have different functions for each select onchange events.
I have renamed the function to `checkvalueProductTag() and checkvalueCategory()`

```
function checkvalueProductTag(val) {
    if(val==="NewSale")
      document.getElementById('actualamt').style.display='block';
    else 
      document.getElementById('actualamt').style.display='none'; 
 }
function checkvalueCategory(val){
    if(val==="SchoolWearAccessories") 
      document.getElementById('schoolwear').style.display='block';
    else 
      document.getElementById('schoolwear').style.display='none'; 
 }
```

Check the updated fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/6hheckao/1/